# prevent padding background-color from overflowing into child element

Tags: html, css, padding

I've googled this a lot but I can't find an answer there or here on SO. I need to figure out how to prevent padding background-color from overflowing into its child element. **The child element can't move out of its place**.

I've tried overflow:hidden, z-index, and pretty much everything.

It's definitely easiest to just see the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/so23hbf0/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar">
<a href="#home">Home</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
<div class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Books & Media</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: yellow;
 }

.navbar a {
    padding: 2rem 1.6rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline;
}

.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Notice how when you hover the links, the black background spills over into the gray "Mega Menu" area. But it doesn't spill up over the top. I want to prevent it spilling over downwards.

Comment: This feels like a pretty bad structure, your nesting seems incorrect, you have block-level elements inside inline elements. I would recommend using nested li's containing links for the basic structure of any menu.

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa It's nested so that a hover will trigger display:block instead of display:none. I left that part out for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: Why can you not just adjust the padding?

Comment: @Turnip Eh it's all about principle. I may want to change the height later and I don't want to do things twice.

Comment: Understood, although you are going to shoot yourself in the foot with that structure, you'll spend many hours debugging something that stems from that structure, I really urge you to try the following structure as a starting point: https://codepen.io/antoniputra/pen/BzyWmb

Comment: @AlexanderDeSousa Cool ok, I'm looking at that now. I'm sure it will help. I got my code from "Mega Menu" at W3schools. Kudos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position `div.dropdown` so you can use `z-index` to control the stack order in relation to surrounding elements, preventing the menu from overlapping.

Only elements that have a position value other than the initial - `static` - can have their stacking context re-arranged with `z-index` see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for examples.

```
div.dropdown {
    /* ... */
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1;
}
```

For example: https://jsfiddle.net/0mczuLsx/

Comment: This is helpful, but do you know how to get it so that the Books & Media link also doesn't spill? Thank you!

Comment: @Mark: Where do you see it "spilling"? Not seeing it on latest Firefox Developer Edition. Also see @Alexander De Sousa comment you really need to re-structure the HTML and make some changes within the CSS. `div.dropdown` shouldn't be an inline element for example.

Comment: Hmm, I'm on Chrome, but I also made the .dropdown-content div positioned relative. This works now like I need it to.

The real-life project is much more complicated and I need the HTML to stay this way it is. See "Mega Menu" on W3schools.

Comment: @Mark: Please don't use W3Schools as a learning resource, it has historically been full of bad practice and misinformation. Read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) or the official [specifications](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/specs.en.html).

Comment: Ok will do, sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navbar {
 overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.navbar a {
 padding: 2rem 1.6rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline;
}

.navbar a:hover {
 background-color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
 background-color: gray;
}

div.dropdown{
    /* ... */
    position: relative; 
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!--Change Html to:-->

<div class="navbar">
 <a href="#home">Home</a>
 <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Books & Media</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <div class="header">
    <h2>Mega Menu</h2>
   </div>  
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: You placed <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Books & Media</a> in the wrong location. That's why Books and Media was not working